# Nouns and verbs which share the same form

Tags: verb, noun

Beside "leben" - *to live*  and  "Leben" - *life*, are there other nouns which have the same form as their verbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Erik is completely right, I don't think that you refer to the gerund. We have to differ between *living* (what Erik's answer is about), and *life, lifetime or existence* (what your question is about).

There are a couple of words which have a further meaning than just *the action of doing something*.

- *essen* (to eat) - *Essen* (food, meal) <sub>(Note: Also a German town)</sub>
- *springen* (to jump) - *Springen* (in sports, e.g. "Skispringen" (ski-jumping))
- *lachen* (to laugh) - *Lachen* (laugh, laughter <sub>(the sound)</sub>)
- *braten* (to fry, to barbecue, to roast) - *Braten* (roast <sub>(meat)</sub>)
- *wagen* (to risk, to dare) - *Wagen* (car, wagon, trolley <sub>(Einkaufswagen)</sub>)
- *leiden* (to suffer) - *Leiden* (complaint <sub>(illness)</sub>, sickness, disease)
  <sub>(also distress (situation) and affliction (pain))</sub>
- *fangen* (to catch) - *Fangen* (tag <sub>(children's game)</sub>)
- *streichen* (to paint) - *Streichen* (gait fault of a horse)
- *regen* (to stir) - *Regen* (rain)
- *wissen* (to know) - *Wissen* (knowledge)
- *trinken* (to drink) - *Trinken* (drink) <sub>(Note: Getränk is more common)</sub>
- *kommen* (to come) - *Kommen* (arrival)
- *leben* (to live) - *Leben* (life, lifetime)

If someone knows a word that is missing yet, please feel free to add or place them in the comments.

Comment: It might be easier just to edit and add to your answer to keep the list all together than to keep adding comment notes. :-) Great work here though!

Comment: @Em1: I've deleted my obsolete comments. After thinking a bit more about those words I see that _Trinken_ is not bad at all, but I guess it's essentially confined to _Essen und Trinken_ in usage. And for _Kommen_ there are indeed some reasonable examples in the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kommen).

Answer (score 8):

You can turn most verbs into a noun without changing the form. In general, this has the same effect as creating a verb's gerund in English:

geben -- *to give* : das Geben -- *giving* 
fliegen -- *to fly* : das Fliegen -- *flying*
...